# Selenium: not stable tests passing

Tags: c#, .net, selenium

In our project we have ~400 UI tests, written on selenium web driver. Tests are run automatically in five browsers(IE, Opera, Chrome, FireFox, Safari) in teamcity build server(running on Win 2012 server). For each build the number of failed tests differs, but when the failed tests are run one by one on my local machine, they successfully pass. Most of the failed tests are "element not found exception". In some cases tests fails in only one browser, eg Safari.

I tried to refactor most of the failed tests using Seleno.TestStack package and page-object pattern, but no matter what, they fail too.

If i ignore the failed test, the remaining tests fail on each build.

Any suggestions on how to handle this situation?

Comment: This is too broad and generic to give a reliable answer. You'd need to debug it, check what the page source & DOM look like at the point of failure and see what's going wrong. Is it actually on the page you think it is?

Comment: I have no idea how it debug. If I run failed test in debug mode on my local machine, its all fine. They only fails if They all runs not one by one. I noticed that when I do browser.GoTo("link") then web driver is lock return from this method unless all page is downloaded. But when I made some button or link click on page - WebDriver dont wait, and I need to use Explicit Wait. In this case frecuency of failing test is lowerst but all the same they fail.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps at all, but look on the site for documentation for `test.stack.white`. They recommend doing tests on a workstation because not all of the automation features are on the server software.